# Add OR in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL query:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.post_author,
    p.post_status,
    p.post_name,
    p.post_parent,
    p.post_type,
    p.post_date,
    p.post_date_gmt,
    p.post_modified,
    p.post_modified_gmt,
    p.comment_count
FROM
    {$wpdb->posts} p
WHERE
    p.post_password = ''
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND YEAR(p.post_date_gmt) = %d
    AND MONTH(p.post_date_gmt) = %d
    {$exPostSQL}
    {$exCatSQL}
ORDER BY
    p.post_date_gmt DESC
```

And I want to adjust it so it looks for `p.post_status = 'publish'` **OR** `p.post_status = 't_active'`.

I tried:

```
AND p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 't_active'
```

But it didn't work. How do you achieve this?

This is an entry level question - SQL is not my jazz.

Comment: `AND (x = 'a' OR x = 'b')` or `AND x IN ('a', 'b')`

Comment: Why don't you use IN()?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: @NicoHaase - The OP would have broken the intended logical operation.  By doing `a AND b AND c OR d` the intention was `a AND b AND (c OR d)` but actually yielded `(a AND b AND c) OR d` due to operator order of precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets to make clear what condition you're doing the OR on:

```
AND (p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 't_active')
```

Alternatively you can use an IN clause:

```
AND p.post_status IN ('publish', 't_active')
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

try to use `AND (p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 't_active')`

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by MatBailie at the comment section - `AND x IN ('a', 'b')` - is in my opinion the "correct" way of writing the code. Meaning more readable and therefore easier to maintain.

Comment: As this has been posted already as an answer, feel free to upvote it instead of duplicating it